# where can i get javax.comm.propertias jar

Tags: java, jar, javax.comm

i want to communicate with another pc  using serial port ,i tried to find this jar file but

i could not success  please help me where  i can get this jar file

javax.comm.propertias.jar

window32com.dll

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you Install JMRI? If not do it

JMRI installer program installs below components into the JRE so they'll be found when the program starts:
**javax.comm.propertias.jar**
**window32com.dll**